# Is there a url rewriting engine for Tomcat/Java?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting, friendly-url

**How can we provide URL-Rewriting support for Tomcat/Java ?**

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) provides this functionality for Apache and can modify URLs even before they reach the handler (e.g. PHP). Is there a similar tool in Java/Tomcat ?

To be more specific we need modifications such as

```
  http://www.somedomain.com/person/1
      Maps to
  http://www.somedomain.com/details?personId=1
```

And this should be transparent to the servlet code, i.e. we should be able to access `request.getParameter("personId")` in the servlet and get the personId (1 in this case).

Did you come across such a scenario ? What tool did you use ? 
Would love to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 30):

See the [URLRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/)

Answer (score 0):

I did run into this scenario but went with front-ending my Tomcat with Apache+mod_rewrite, to keep it simple. Besides there are other advantages of front-ending with Apache HTTPd depending on your use case.