# How to rewrite URL in Tomcat 6

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, struts2

I'll build a web application and I want to use url rewriting.
In apache this is done with mod_rewrite.
But how can I rewrite urls with Tomcat 6?

I want to use Struts 2 framework.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've used [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) as a critical component of a couple of my tomcat-based apps, and have been totally happy with it.

Comment: Have you used it with Struts?

Comment: No; I've never used Struts at all, sorry!

Comment: But the author of UrlRewriteFilter does mention Struts in particular on the front page, in a context that suggests that it's compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-configuration.html) in your struts.xml:

```
<action name="*Crud" class="example.Crud" method="{1}">
...
```

Then I think you can set your default action extension to / in [struts.properties](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/strutsproperties.html):

```
struts.action.extension=/
```

As for the URL filter, [here's a good blog post](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/extensionless_urls_in_java_web).

Answer (score 1):

It [could be](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors#Q3) a good idea to have Apache as a web server for static content in front of Tomcat application server.

You can then use [Apache's mod_rewrite and Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html).

In any case, there's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950497/is-there-a-url-rewriting-engine-for-tomcat-java).