# Wordpress-like Urlrewriting in JSP, Tomcat with Urlrewritefilter

Tags: wordpress, jsp, tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am developing a simple cms for an online health magazine using JSP,Tomcat and urlrewritefilter for url rewriting.
I am migrating content from wordpress and should keep the permalinks on the site.
Permalinks looks like below with only letters and numbers.

```
http://www.example.com/post-or-category-name-with-letters-or-1234/
```

I want to rewrite my url in my jsp application so that I can have urls like above. 
Rewrite Rule should work as follows.

```
http://www.example.com/post/?pid=1234&name=post-name
http://www.example.com/category/?cid=1234&slug=category-slug
```

into

```
http://www.example.com/post-name/
http://www.example.com/category-slug/
```

And of course vice versa.

How can I have a wordpress-like permalink structure using urlrewritefilter? Do I need to write a Servlet for getting the id of name or slug from DB?

Anybody has an idea how to do that or done it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already done a JavaServer Faces CMS with custom URL for posts and categories. I've used basically `javax.servlet.Filter` and `javax.faces.application.ViewHandler`. Since you are in straight JSP you won't need `javax.faces.application.ViewHandler`.

How I declared my filter :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.spectotechnologies.jsf.filters.URLFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Basic Filter implementation :

```
/**
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
public class URLFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest p_oRequest, ServletResponse p_oResponse, FilterChain p_oChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // Determining new url, get parameters, etc
        p_oRequest.getRequestDispatcher("newurl").forward(p_oRequest,p_oResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig p_oConfiguration) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented something similar, however I used tomcat's error page forwarding for 404 code(e.g error.jsp) and made DBWorker calls, got the id and loaded the actual page content in this error.jsp. I will try your implementation also.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer lies into : 
[How to rewrite URL in Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563799/how-to-rewrite-url-in-tomcat-6)

[Is there a url rewriting engine for Tomcat/Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950497/is-there-a-url-rewriting-engine-for-tomcat-java)

Comment: I have already checked those before. I am trying the examples section in tuckey's urlrewritefilter however couldn't come up with a solution using only tomcat + urlrewritefilter.