# How to point to html files in different location?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

my situation looks like this:

```
MyApplication(folder)
|
| - server (folder)
|      |
|      | - some structure (folder)
|      |     |
|            | - login.jsp
|
| - client (folder) 
|     |
|     | - clientSoftware (folder)
|     |     |
|     |     | - index.html
|     |     | - something.html
|     |     | - otherSomething.html
```

I'm running it on Apache Tomcat server and what I would like to get is this:

localhost:8080/NameOfApplication/index.html

and not
localhost:8080/NameOfApplication/client/clientSoftware/index.html

I'm using spring mvc. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You are using Spring MVC and Apache server... I hope it would be Apache Tomcat right, please clear because if you are using only Apache Web Server then I don't think you will be left with any solution...

Comment: well but of course, sorry. Just correct it = )

Comment: seems related to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1563808/2636001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/) specifically part 6.

```
<bean name="/welcome.htm" .
     class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HelloWorldController" />
```

Notice how the web url is now `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome.htm` when he declares the bean.

Comment: I think that can do the trick. I'll test is as soon as I can :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, In Spring MVC, If you are using Annotation then,

As an Example,

### HTML

```
<a href="cabBooking">Book Cab</a>
```

### Spring Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/cabBooking", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getCabBookingPage() {

        ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView("cabBooking"); //here it will search "cabBooking.jsp" in /WEB-INF/pages/ and same mapping you can find in dispatcher file.
```

Also, whatever your mapping is to invoke this function will be visible to user and actual page is what you will p
            return mnv;

```
   }
}
```

### dispatcher file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.on.transport" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Add Spring MVC Dispatcher class mapping in web.xml. Have a look at any Spring MVC example for web.xml changes.