# Can I debug WebApps in Tomcat and Eclipse with blank project name?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm developing multiple java-ee web apps in Eclipse kepler & tomcat7 and now everything goes well. I get a specific app with `http://localhost:8080/appname`.

But can I do some settings to make this project with a blank name so that I can visit it by `http://localhost:8080/`

[Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application) may not work for the server integration way in Eclipse.

PS: Running on Windows XP with eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32 and tomcat7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating (or renaming) a project called "ROOT" allowed me to do this within Eclipse.

When you initially "Run on Server" it will load the app using the long-form URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/ROOT
```

But if you navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

You'll see it hits the same page.

One caveat is that in the Tomcat settings page in Eclipse, you'll need to ensure the Server Location is set to "Use workspace metadata". I initially had it set to "Use Tomcat installation" and calling the default `http://localhost:8080/` URL would just load Tomcat's default page (presumably because a ROOT application already exists / takes precedence).

**Update**

I've found you can achieve the same result without changing your project name. Simply edit your Eclipse project's `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file and change the context-root property to "ROOT" like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="YourProjectName">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/YourProjectName/build/classes"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="ROOT"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Where "YourProjectName" is the name of your project, obviously. :)

**Second Update**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334309/575766) on a related question you can actually change the content-root from the GUI in Eclipse but going to "Web Project Settings" in your project settings.

Comment: I just simplely rename the project into `ROOT` and it works !

Answer (score 2):

From experience, I would say that it cannot be done.

Since we cannot hide the URL.

Instead you can do,

- Redirect the URL to application server via web server(Apache
  WebServer) so when you hit `http://localhost:8080/` it will
  automatically redirect to the mapped URL say,
  `http://localhost:8080/appname`

  Cf : [How to rewrite URL in Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1563799/1140748) and 
    [Is there a url rewriting engine for Tomcat/Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/950497/1140748)
- You can develop your application as a single page application and
  replace your content by updating div and span using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). If you give `http://localhost:8080/appname` without changing or redirecting the URL we can do our tasks.

Comment: Your approach will work, but I don't believe it is necessary. Please see my solution to achieve this from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

well there are quite easy ways to do this:

1. double click the Server Name (e.g Tomcat 7) in the Servers view;
2. go the `Modules` tab;
3. select the `appname` and click edit, then leave the path to blank