# With Tomcat Servlet container how do I serve jsp files as html files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

So I have files such as index.jsp and download.jsp in my web application widget.war and am using Tomcat 7. I would like these files to be accessible from the internet as html files i.e

- http:/www.mycompany.com/widget/index.html
- http:/www.mycompany.com/widget/download.html

Questions:

1. How do I do this, I know it can be done as I did it about 5 years ago but cannot remember how.
2. Is it a good idea, it seems like a good idea as users are familar with html but jsps, and returning as jsps shows an implementation detail, but does it matter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950497/is-there-a-url-rewriting-engine-for-tomcat-java

Comment: It doesn't matter. End users usually don't care about the URLs, and the fact that it ends up with .jsp or .html doesn't make your app more or less secure.

Comment: @DRCB there wasn't any good answer there that match best with this problem at the link. you can do it with just the url-mapping

Comment: Well jsp pages can be accessed similarly with the plain html pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `*.html` through your application's web.xml to the `jsp` servlet defined in tomcat_path/conf/web.xml.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, extensions in general are an implementation detail, so it makes no big difference to your users if the URL ends with .html or .jsp. Most won't probably care anyway.