# Redirecting http://www.example.com to http://example.com

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

How do I redirect http://www.example.com to http://example.com in Tomcat? All the documentation focuses on Apache, but I'm hosting a Java app.

Comment: Is this application you are developing? Can you modify this application by adding extra files? Isn't this duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950497/is-there-a-url-rewriting-engine-for-tomcat-java ??

Comment: I used the config on this question and it works like a charm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411311/redirect-to-a-different-host-in-spring-boot-non-www-to-www-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Apache

This should be something in the lines of

```
# .htaccess file contents
# Apache has the same docroot as the Java web app.
# Java webapp is running on port 8084
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# For sites running on a port other than 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://domain.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]

# And for a site running on port 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://domain.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

#### Tomcat

You can use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in Tomcat. A rule like this should work for you in **/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml**:

```
<rule enabled="true">
    <name>Force HTTPS example</name>
    <note>Automatically redirects user requests.</note>
    <from>http://domain.com/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://www.domain.com/</to>
</rule>
```

Not sure if I made typo's, wrote this on top of head

Comment: @bluedevil2k Yes, i mixed them up.

Comment: @Margus "Not sure if I made typo's, wrote this on top of the head" - That's why you forgot to edit "Force HTTPS example"?

Answer (score 3):

In Tomcat8 - you have this option
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

If your site is a single webapp - add this to ROOT.xml

```
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
```

Then put `rewrite.config` in your WEB-INF of your webapp

Which would look like this:

```
  RewriteCond  %{SERVER_NAME}  ! ^www.example.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule  ^/(.*)          http://example.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

This can also be applied at the Host level too so it can work across multiple webapps.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Here's how I solved the problem: First, I added `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />` to `conf/context.xml` and then `RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com$ [NC]` and `RewriteRule  ^/(.*)        http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` to `rewrite.config` in my `WEB-INF` folder. Please note, however, that *example.com* redirects to ***www**.example.com*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying this in the local environment.

Open the "hosts" file and add ip entry.

Eg:

```
127.0.0.1     www.example.com
```

"hosts" file is located in the following location depending on the OS.

**If you are in Windows**

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

**If you are in Linux**

```
/etc/hosts
```

Open browser and try now. It will work for both (example.com or www.example.com).
In Hosted environment, this would have been taken care at the DNS level. So no worries.

Note: This will work in the machines where you have modified hosts file.